# Extracting elementary stream type using ffprobe

Tags: streaming, ffprobe

I'm trying to extract the elementary stream type using `ffprobe` (as in the PES header).

`ffprobe` gives info about the codec in the form of `codec_tag`, but that isn't necessary the elementary stream type. Specifically, if the stream type is `0x06` (private), it behaves somewhat different.

Bottom line, I need the elementary stream type.

Answer (score 0):

If the input format is MPEG-TS, I believe you can use [tsduck](https://tsduck.io/) to get that.

Otherwise, try [MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo), which has a multi-platform GUI and CLI options available.  The CLI version is convenient to use from scripts.